# Getting an imagedata from a html object in angular application and send it to a rest server

Tags: angular, html2canvas

What i want to do is:

Getting an imagedata from a html object in my angular (in Typescript! no javascript!) application and send it to my rest server.
This should by done by my service with function `set_Image`.

So far everything works well and i get the correct data, shown with the console.log function.
Also the `http.post(url,Image64).pipe(tap(Image64 => console.log(Image64)));` works well in other service functions.

Because i don't get any access to my variables in the `function (canvas) {}` I declared the necessary variables in function body
But now i got the error:

```
"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined."
```

I'm now working on this issue for two weeks and all my researches couldn't fix the problem.
Please help.

The Code:

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders }            from '@angular/common/http';
import * as html2canvas from 'html2canvas'

const url1 = 'http://localhost:55320/api/Server/';
.
.
.
  set_Image(container:string)
  {      
    html2canvas(document.getElementById(container))
    .then(function (canvas) 
    {
      var Image64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
      console.log("CANVAS: ", Image64);
      const url = url1 + '0/set_Image';
      var http:HttpClient;
      http.post(url,Image64).pipe(tap(Image64 => console.log(Image64)));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like in constructor, have you created instance for HttpClient Service.

constructor(private http: HttpClient)

You can access Http related public API's using.

this.http.post().

Comment: If i try to use the declared http objekt inside the function body function (canvas) {} with this... the type off http is "any". In this body HAVE NO ACCES TO MY VARIABLES!

Comment: inside set_Image() method, set const me = this;  Access using me.http.post()

Comment: Solved it by storing the canvas element in locale storage and later load it from there when i need it.

Comment: Bad practice, but it works and i don't have the time to work for days on that issue. Time is money.